# Active Directory setup with Profile Path and Home Folder

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, active-directory, windows-server-2012, roaming-profiles

I have roaming profiles turned on. I was wondering what the different was between Profile Path and Home Folder in the Active Directory setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shameless, blatant plagiarism:](https://serverfault.com/questions/29948/difference-between-profile-and-home-path)

> The profile path is the location of the user's user profile. The
>   "Home" path may be the same, but it could be set to another location
>   (via the user account properties).
>
> The home path is a bit of a vestigial thing. It dates back to Windows
>   NT, prior to the 'My Documents' directory. I believe the original
>   intent was to provide a "Home Directory" similiar to Unix
>   environments, but the user profile ended up (with the advent of "My
>   Documents") being the default storage location for files (which led to
>   the whole "redirect folders out of the user profile" functionality
>   that came on after W2K).
>
> "Folder Redirection" can use the legacy home path setting as the
>   destination for redirecting the "My Documents" path. This can be handy
>   if you have groups of users who need their "My Documents" path
>   redirected to various server computers, as you can set a different
>   home path on a user-for-user basis. (You can do the same thing w/
>   multiple group policy objects, or with a single folder redirection
>   policy based on group membership, too.)

Comment: Ah, ok. I am using Profile Path and all the My Docs, Pic, ect... look to move around but I just figured that is what the Home Folder was for and the Profile Path was just desktop and such.